# Should I keep monerod instances active on mining rigs?

Tags: monerod, security, mining, network

Does it help the Monero network if I keep monerod instances active on different rigs? Or is it not useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, 1 Monerod instance per internet IP address, physical location, or operator is adequate to enhance network decentralization.

Comment: So more monerod instances behind the same IP are not useful in anyway. Right?

Comment: In my opinion, it could be useful (as long as you have port `18080` open to receive incoming connections), because it'd allow more people to sync off of you.